# Open interval on $\mathbb{R}$ with the lower limit topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $B'=\{[x,y):x<y, x,y\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then lower limit topology $\tau_l$ generated by $B'$ is strictly finer than standard topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, every element in $\tau_l$ is contained in $\tau$. But the topology generated a basis is the collection of unions of elements in the basis. In particular, an open interval in $\tau$ is a union of elements in $B'$. But how could I obtain open interval by taking union of elements in $B'$?

Comment: $(a,b)=\bigcup ([a+\frac 1 n ,b)$

Comment: Thanks. Now I see.